# I can only access elements of a vector while inside a for loop

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, stringstream

I have a function with a vector that is passed in by reference. I am able to use the vector inside a for loop to write its contents to a file. However, if I try to access any index of the vector outside of the loop, is gives me this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 10) >= this->size() (which is 0)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is my code:

```
void writeFileVector(vector<string> &wordVector, char *argv[]) {
    ofstream newFileName;
    stringstream ss;

    ss << argv[1];
    string argumentString = ss.str();               // This code is just for creating the name
    ss.str(""); // Clear the stringstream           // of the file
    ss << argumentString << "_vector.txt";          //
    string fileName = ss.str();                     //
    newFileName.open(fileName.c_str());             //

    cout << wordVector.at(0) << endl;               // THIS GIVES ME THE ERROR
    
    for (int i = 0; i < wordVector.size(); i++) {
        cout << wordVector.at(0) << endl;           // This would not give an error, but it also
                                                    // doesn't output anything to the terminal.

        newFileName << wordVector.at(i) << endl;    // This is okay
    }

    newFileName.close();
}
```

Comment: Your vector is empty. The code inside the loop doesn't print anything because it never gets executed.

Comment: In your own words, why do you expect `wordVector.at(0)` to work? What value should it return? Where is the code that creates the `wordVector`? Did it actually put any words into the vector? Are you sure? Did you check? (Hint: how would you check?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can only access elements of a vector while inside a for loop

No, you can access elements of a vector anywhere where the vector is is scope. But you need to ensure you're accessing *actual* elements, not made-up ones :-)

With regard to the (slightly modified) code:

```
//cout << wordVector.at(0) << endl;             // THIS GIVES ME THE ERROR
for (int i = 0; i < wordVector.size(); i++) {
    cout << wordVector.at(0) << endl;           // THIS DOESN'T
}
```

When the vector is empty, the `cout` inside the loop is never executed, because the loop body doesn't *run.* That's because `i < wordVector.size()` *starts out* as false because both `i` and `wordVector.size()` are zero.

If you were to modify the loop so that the body *did* run, you would see it also fails *within* the loop:

```
//cout << wordVector.at(0) << endl;             // THIS GIVES ME THE ERROR
for (int i = -1; i < wordVector.size(); i++) {
    cout << wordVector.at(0) << endl;           // SO DOES THIS
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I realized that I wasn't running the program with the right command line arguments. I was supposed to specify a filename that the vector would be created from. So since I didn't specify any file, the vector was empty.